# Do I need Microsoft.net Framework updates?

Tags: updates, windows-update

Do I need Microsoft.net Framework updates? Due to using an Ipad, I am not on my laptop very often, but I like to install the correct updates when I do. I just it use mainly for the internet and Word. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

It's always a good idea. They are frequently deployed to fix security concerns and address compatibility issues. Staying up to date on your framework updates is not a heavy task and helps to ensure your experience on the Microsoft platform.

**[Good article on why it's important](http://lifehacker.com/5791578/what-is-the-net-framework-and-why-do-i-need-it)**